# Python: confused about assignment in nested lists

Tags: python, list, nested

I put a polynomial in a nested list; for example `5X^3+4X^2+8X`.  I stored coefficients (5,4,8) in first list and exponents(3,2,1) in second:

```
polynom = [[5,4,8],[3,2,0]]
```

Then I define a function to pop the last term of coefficients and exponents like this

```
def expon_coef_pop(seq):
    expon = seq[1]
    coef = seq[0]
    expon.pop()
    coef.pop()
    return coef, expon

print(expon_coef_pop(polynom))
print(polynom)

# polynom changed into [[5,4],[4,2]]
```

Surprisingly, I found the value of `polynom` turned into `[[5,4],[3,2]]`. 
I thought I just modified value of `expon` and `coef`.

I don't want to change the value of polynomial.

How could this happen, and how to deal with this problem?  I am confused about why the `polynorm` changed not the function.  (I just wrote the function for a simple example.)

Comment: how is it 8X shouldnt it be 8 as X^0 is 1

Comment: `coeff` and `expon` are references to the same list objects as `seq[0]` and `seq[1]`.

Comment: Sorry, a mistake (●'◡'●)

Answer (score 1):

Both `coef` and `expon` are references pointing at the same list objects as `seq[0]` and `seq[1]` correspondingly. You will need to copy the lists before popping from them, which can also be done all in one step:

```
def expon_coef_pop(seq):
    return seq[0][:-1], seq[1][:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you pass your lists by reference. Compare with this assignment with copying

```
expon = list(seq[1])
coef = list(seq[0])
```

Comment: That`s just what I need! Thank you!

Comment: it said 'TypeError: 'list' object is not callable'

Comment: @SeanXie try my answer and let me know

Comment: @SeanXie I checked it on both python 2 and python 3 and it works. Maybe you have object called 'list' in another part of your program? If it's true, just rename it.

Comment: I just tried expon=list(polynom[0]) in python 3.5 console. It still said TypeError

Answer (score 0):

Just change simple modification. You can try it:

you need to Change

```
expon = seq[1] to expon = seq[1][:]
coef = seq[0] to coef = seq[0][:]
```

Your final code:

```
polynom = [[5,4,8],[3,2,0]]
def expon_coef_pop(seq):
    expon = seq[1][:]
    coef = seq[0][:]
    expon.pop()
    coef.pop()
    return coef, expon

print(expon_coef_pop(polynom))
print(polynom)
```